# component is not defined in react

Tags: reactjs, components

so i'm trying to build a landing page using react and  in my code i get the error component not defined.

```
const http = new HttpService();

class App extends Componenet {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        http.getProducts();
    }
}
```

not sure what im doing wrong as i'm new to react would love for some help

Comment: Please add to your question the full error message

Comment: check your component spelling "componenet"

Comment: Please add more code of your App component and code from where you are importing it

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported `Component` from react?

if not - import like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class App extends Component{}
```

or use directly like this

```
class App extends React.Component{}
```

> Note- you imported Componenet not Component, just change to Component.